# Problemas al intentar cargar datos en documento XML desde formulario Java Swing

Tags: java, xml, java-swing

Me estoy pegando con un proyecto que almacena datos en un finero XML
El fichero se ha creado con un método anterior, o sea, ya lo tengo creado

EL mñetodo de creación del mismo es el siguiente:

```
public void metodoCrearXML() {

    try {
        // Creo una instancia de DocumentBuilderFactory
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        // Creo un documentBuilder
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        // Creo un DOMImplementation
        DOMImplementation implementation = builder.getDOMImplementation();

        // Creo un documento con un elemento raiz
        Document documento = implementation.createDocument(null, "Restaurante", null);
        documento.setXmlVersion("1.0");

        // Creo los elementos
        Element Bodas = documento.createElement("Bodas");
        Element Boda = documento.createElement("Boda");

        // Novio
        Element Novio = documento.createElement("Novio");
        //Text textNovio = documento.createTextNode("Carlos");
        //Novio.appendChild(textNovio);
        Boda.appendChild(Novio);

        // Novia
        Element Novia = documento.createElement("Novia");
        //Text textNovia = documento.createTextNode("Susana");
        //Novia.appendChild(textNovio);
        Boda.appendChild(Novia);

        // Invitados
        Element Invitados = documento.createElement("Invitados");
        //Text textInvitados = documento.createTextNode("220");
        //Invitados.appendChild(textInvitados);
        Boda.appendChild(Invitados);
        
        // Fecha
        Element Fecha = documento.createElement("Fecha");
        //Text textFecha = documento.createTextNode("23/06/2001");
        //Fecha.appendChild(textFecha);
        Boda.appendChild(Fecha);
        
        // Menú
        Element Menu = documento.createElement("Menu");
        //Text textFecha = documento.createTextNode("23/06/2001");
        //Menu.appendChild(textFecha);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Sopa
        Element Sopa = documento.createElement("Sopa");
        //Text textSopa = documento.createTextNode("Sopa de Marisco");
        //Sopa.appendChild(textSopa);
        Menu.appendChild(Sopa);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Aperitivo
        Element Aperitivo = documento.createElement("Aperitivo");
        //Text textAperitivo = documento.createTextNode("Langosta del Cantábrico");
        //Aperitivo.appendChild(textAperitivo);
        Menu.appendChild(Aperitivo);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Pescado
        Element Pescado = documento.createElement("Pescado");
        //Text textPescado = documento.createTextNode("Lubina al cava Moet Chandon");
        //Pescado.appendChild(textPescado);
        Menu.appendChild(Pescado);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Carne
        Element Carne = documento.createElement("Carne");
        //Text textCarne = documento.createTextNode("Cabritu con patatinos");
        //Carne.appendChild(textCarne);
        Menu.appendChild(Carne);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Postre
        Element Postre = documento.createElement("Postre");
        //Text textPostre = documento.createTextNode("Tarta de Fresas Silvestres");
        //Postre.appendChild(textPostre);
        Menu.appendChild(Postre);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Menú
        Element Extras = documento.createElement("Extras");
        //Text textFecha = documento.createTextNode("23/06/2001");
        //Menu.appendChild(textFecha);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_1
        Element Extra_1 = documento.createElement("Extra_1");
        //Text textExtra_1 = documento.createTextNode("Emplatado");
        //Extra_1.appendChild(textExtra_1);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_1);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_2
        Element Extra_2 = documento.createElement("Extra_2");
        //Text textExtra_2 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Extra_2.appendChild(textExtra_2);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_2);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_3
        Element Extra_3 = documento.createElement("Extra_3");
        //Text textExtra_3 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Extra_3.appendChild(textExtra_3);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_3);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_4
        Element Extra_4 = documento.createElement("Extra_4");
        //Text textExtra_4 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Extra_4.appendChild(textExtra_4);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_4);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_5
        Element Extra_5 = documento.createElement("Extra_5");
        //Text textExtra_5 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Extra_5.appendChild(textExtra_5);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_5);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_6
        Element Extra_6 = documento.createElement("Extra_6");
        //Text textExtra_6 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Extra_6.appendChild(textExtra_6);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_6);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Servicios
        Element Servicios = documento.createElement("Servicios");
        //Text textFecha = documento.createTextNode("23/06/2001");
        //Menu.appendChild(textFecha);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio_1
        Element Servicio_1 = documento.createElement("Servicio_1");
        //Text textServicio_1 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Servicio_1.appendChild(textServicio_1);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_1);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio2
        Element Servicio_2 = documento.createElement("Servicio_2");
        //Text textServicio_2 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Servicio_2.appendChild(textServicio_2);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_2);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio3
        Element Servicio_3 = documento.createElement("Servicio_3");
        //Text textServicio_3 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Servicio_3.appendChild(textServicio_3);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_3);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio4
        Element Servicio_4 = documento.createElement("Servicio_4");
        //Text textServicio_4 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Servicio_4.appendChild(textServicio_4);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_4);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio5
        Element Servicio_5 = documento.createElement("Servicio_5");
        //Text textServicio_5 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Servicio_5.appendChild(textServicio_5);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_5);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio6
        Element Servicio_6 = documento.createElement("Servicio_6");
        //Text textServicio_6 = documento.createTextNode("Cubresillas");
        //Servicio_6.appendChild(textServicio_6);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_6);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);

        // Añado al elemento coches el elemento coche
        Bodas.appendChild(Boda);

        // Añado al root el elemento coches
        documento.getDocumentElement().appendChild(Bodas);

        // Asocio el source con el Document
        Source source = new DOMSource(documento);
        // Creo el Result, indicado que fichero se va a crear
        Result result = new StreamResult(new File("Restaurante.xml"));

        // Creo un transformer, se crea el fichero XML
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Una vez creado el fichero XML, su aspecto es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Restaurante>
    -<Bodas>
        -<Boda>
            <Novio/>
            <Novia/>
            <Invitados/>
            <Fecha/>
            -<Menu>
                <Sopa/>
                <Aperitivo/>
                <Pescado/>
                <Carne/>
                <Postre/>
            </Menu>
            -<Extras>
                <Extra_1/>
                <Extra_2/>
                <Extra_3/>
                <Extra_4/>
                <Extra_5/>
                <Extra_6/>
            </Extras>
            -<Servicios>
                <Servicio_1/>
                <Servicio_2/>
                <Servicio_3/>
                <Servicio_4/>
                <Servicio_5/>
                <Servicio_6/>
            </Servicios>
        </Boda>
    </Bodas>
</Restaurante>
```

Ahora lo que pretendería, sería agregar los datos al fichero anterior, pero tras una decena de pruebas, no lo logro.
No se como se podrían agregar los datos, os paso el método que tengo para intentarlo

```
public void metodoGuardarDatosXML(String[] boda){
    

    novio = boda[0];
    novia = boda[1];
    invitados = boda[2];
    fecha = boda[3];
    
    sopa = boda[4];
    aperitivo = boda[5];
    pescado = boda[6];
    carne = boda[7];
    postre = boda[8];
    
    extra_1 = boda[9];
    extra_2 = boda[10];
    extra_3 = boda[11];
    extra_4 = boda[12];
    extra_5 = boda[13];
    extra_6 = boda[14];
    
    servicio_1 = boda[15];
    servicio_2 = boda[16];
    servicio_3 = boda[17];
    servicio_4 = boda[18];
    servicio_5 = boda[19];
    servicio_6 = boda[20];
    
    neto = boda[21];
    iva10 = boda[22];
    iva21 = boda[23];
    total = boda[24];

    try {
        // Creo una instancia de DocumentBuilderFactory
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        // Creo un documentBuilder
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        // Creo un DOMImplementation
        DOMImplementation implementation = builder.getDOMImplementation();

        // Creo un documento con un elemento raiz
        Document documento = implementation.createDocument(null, "Restaurante", null);
        documento.setXmlVersion("1.0");

        // Creo los elementos
        Element Bodas = documento.createElement("Bodas");
        Element Boda = documento.createElement("Boda");

        // Novio
        Element Novio = documento.createElement("Novio");
        Text textNovio = documento.createTextNode(novio);
        Novio.appendChild(textNovio);
        Boda.appendChild(Novio);

        // Novia
        Element Novia = documento.createElement("Novia");
        Text textNovia = documento.createTextNode(novia);
        Novia.appendChild(textNovio);
        Boda.appendChild(Novia);

        // Invitados
        Element Invitados = documento.createElement("Invitados");
        Text textInvitados = documento.createTextNode(invitados);
        Invitados.appendChild(textInvitados);
        Boda.appendChild(Invitados);
        
        // Fecha
        Element Fecha = documento.createElement("Fecha");
        Text textFecha = documento.createTextNode(fecha);
        Fecha.appendChild(textFecha);
        Boda.appendChild(Fecha);
        
        // Menú
        Element Menu = documento.createElement("Menu");
        //Text textFecha = documento.createTextNode("23/06/2001");
        //Menu.appendChild(textFecha);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Sopa
        Element Sopa = documento.createElement("Sopa");
        Text textSopa = documento.createTextNode(sopa);
        Sopa.appendChild(textSopa);
        Menu.appendChild(Sopa);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Aperitivo
        Element Aperitivo = documento.createElement("Aperitivo");
        Text textAperitivo = documento.createTextNode(aperitivo);
        Aperitivo.appendChild(textAperitivo);
        Menu.appendChild(Aperitivo);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Pescado
        Element Pescado = documento.createElement("Pescado");
        Text textPescado = documento.createTextNode(pescado);
        Pescado.appendChild(textPescado);
        Menu.appendChild(Pescado);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Carne
        Element Carne = documento.createElement("Carne");
        Text textCarne = documento.createTextNode(carne);
        Carne.appendChild(textCarne);
        Menu.appendChild(Carne);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Postre
        Element Postre = documento.createElement("Postre");
        Text textPostre = documento.createTextNode(postre);
        Postre.appendChild(textPostre);
        Menu.appendChild(Postre);
        Boda.appendChild(Menu);
        
        // Menú
        Element Extras = documento.createElement("Extras");
        //Text textFecha = documento.createTextNode("23/06/2001");
        //Menu.appendChild(textFecha);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_1
        Element Extra_1 = documento.createElement("Extra_1");
        Text textExtra_1 = documento.createTextNode(extra_1);
        Extra_1.appendChild(textExtra_1);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_1);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_2
        Element Extra_2 = documento.createElement("Extra_2");
        Text textExtra_2 = documento.createTextNode(extra_2);
        Extra_2.appendChild(textExtra_2);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_2);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_3
        Element Extra_3 = documento.createElement("Extra_3");
        Text textExtra_3 = documento.createTextNode(extra_3);
        Extra_3.appendChild(textExtra_3);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_3);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_4
        Element Extra_4 = documento.createElement("Extra_4");
        Text textExtra_4 = documento.createTextNode(extra_4);
        Extra_4.appendChild(textExtra_4);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_4);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_5
        Element Extra_5 = documento.createElement("Extra_5");
        Text textExtra_5 = documento.createTextNode(extra_5);
        Extra_5.appendChild(textExtra_5);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_5);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Extra_6
        Element Extra_6 = documento.createElement("Extra_6");
        Text textExtra_6 = documento.createTextNode(extra_6);
        Extra_6.appendChild(textExtra_6);
        Extras.appendChild(Extra_6);
        Boda.appendChild(Extras);
        
        // Servicios
        Element Servicios = documento.createElement("Servicios");
        //Text textFecha = documento.createTextNode("23/06/2001");
        //Menu.appendChild(textFecha);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio_1
        Element Servicio_1 = documento.createElement("Servicio_1");
        Text textServicio_1 = documento.createTextNode(servicio_1);
        Servicio_1.appendChild(textServicio_1);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_1);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio2
        Element Servicio_2 = documento.createElement("Servicio_2");
        Text textServicio_2 = documento.createTextNode(servicio_2);
        Servicio_2.appendChild(textServicio_2);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_2);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio3
        Element Servicio_3 = documento.createElement("Servicio_3");
        Text textServicio_3 = documento.createTextNode(servicio_3);
        Servicio_3.appendChild(textServicio_3);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_3);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio4
        Element Servicio_4 = documento.createElement("Servicio_4");
        Text textServicio_4 = documento.createTextNode(servicio_4);
        Servicio_4.appendChild(textServicio_4);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_4);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio5
        Element Servicio_5 = documento.createElement("Servicio_5");
        Text textServicio_5 = documento.createTextNode(servicio_5);
        Servicio_5.appendChild(textServicio_5);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_5);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);
        
        // Servicio6
        Element Servicio_6 = documento.createElement("Servicio_6");
        Text textServicio_6 = documento.createTextNode(servicio_6);
        Servicio_6.appendChild(textServicio_6);
        Servicios.appendChild(Servicio_6);
        Boda.appendChild(Servicios);

        // Añado al elemento Boda el elemento Bodas
        Bodas.appendChild(Boda);

        // Añado al root el elemento Bodas
        documento.getDocumentElement().appendChild(Bodas);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(documento);
        
        // Asocio el source con el Document
        //Source source = new DOMSource(documento);
        // Creo el Result, indicado que fichero se va a crear
        Result result = new StreamResult("D:/PresupuestoBoda/Restaurante.xml");
        //Result result = new StreamResult(new File("Restaurante.xml"));

        // Creo un transformer, se crea el fichero XML
        //Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        
        //Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        //DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        //Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
        //StreamResult result = new StreamResult();
        //Result result = new StreamResult(file);
        //transformer.transform (fuente, resultado); 
        
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //try {
        //    //Obtenemos el document del fichero XML existente
        //    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        //    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        //    document = db.parse(new File(URI));
        //    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        //} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        //    e.printStackTrace();
        //} catch (SAXException sax) {
        //    e.printStackTrace();
        //} catch (IOException ioe) {
        //    e.printStackTrace();
        //}

        //Creamos un nuevo elemento en la casa
        //Element terraza = document.createElement("Terraza");
        //Le añadimos una característica
        //Element tamano = document.createElement("Tamano");
        //Le añadimos su valor
        //Text valor = document.createTextNode("20m2");

        //Añadimos la información a la casa ya existente
        //NodeList nodoRaiz = document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Casa");
        //nodoRaiz.item(0).appendChild(terraza);
        //terraza.appendChild(tamano);
        //tamano.appendChild(valor);

        //Guardamos la nueva estructura la fichero XML
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Básicamente es el mismo método que utilicé para crear el fichero, y no se como podría hacer, para ahora intentar agregar datos al mismo

La idea sería ir agregando una boda a continuación de otra

Alguien me podría asesorar ?

gracias

EDITADO:

Conjunto de excepciones:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at PresupuestoBoda.PresupuestoBoda.metodoCrearArrayDatos(PresupuestoBoda.java:1345)
at PresupuestoBoda.PresupuestoBoda.actionPerformed(PresupuestoBoda.java:273)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Si ya tienes un documento XML, puedes utilizar `builder.parse("restaurante.xml")` para obtener el objeto `Document`. Entonces puedes crear los elementos que quieres añadir (`Element boda = document.createElement("boda"); ...`) y insertarlo con `document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("bodas").item(0).appendChild(boda);`.

Comment: Pues siento ser tan nulo, Martin Honnen, pero no logro hacer bien lo que me dices.
Tras varios intentos, solo me aparecen errores

Comment: Si el error es `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at PresupuestoBoda.PresupuestoBoda.metodoCrearArrayDatos(PresupuestoBoda.java:1345)` sería conveniente que mostraras el método metodoCrearArrayDatos y la línea exacta 1345. ¿Tienes otro array que `String[] boda`?